# Save array value instead of index from select form

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravelcollective

I have this array in my controller `$status=array('Ended', 'Processing', 'Canceled');` and I send it by `return view('Form.FormEdit')->with('status', $status)` to my view.

In the select it shows the values contained in each index 
`{{Form::select('status', $status, null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Select status'))}}` but it saves the index number and I don't want that.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: What do you want to save ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in controller you can make array like below and pass to view:

```
$status=[
    'Ended' => 'Ended',
    'Processing' => 'Processing',
    'Canceled' => 'Canceled'
];

return view('Form.FormEdit')->with('status', $status)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the text, you need to have an array with text keys. For now, your array is only an indexed array (0, 1, 2 ...).

You can use this :

```
return view('Form.FormEdit')->with('status', array_combine($status, $status));
```